# POSIX array and loop

Tags: bash, loops, posix

I make an array of files as follows, and then "source" those files. I am also trying to make a script as close to POSIX possible so I don't have issues running it in different shells.

```
set -- path alias function
for file in "${@}"; do
    [ -r "${SELF_PATH_DIR}.${file}" ] && [ -f "${SELF_PATH_DIR}.${file}" ] && . "${SELF_PATH_DIR}.${file}";
done
```

It works, but I don't like the fact that I have to specify `${SELF_PATH_DIR}.` many times, so that the string takes the real path to the files (`/Users/karlsd/dotfiles/.path`, etc.).

Is there any way to make it simpler? For example, to add `/Users/karlsd/dotfiles/.` to each item before the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just assign `"${SELF_PATH_DIR}.${file}"` to a temporary variable or modify the same variable.

By the way: If the loop is the only spot where you are using `set --`/`$@` then you can iterate directly over the list:

```
for file in path alias function; do
    file="${SELF_PATH_DIR}.${file}"
    [ -r "$file" ] && [ -f "$file" ] && . "$file";
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually have a potentially larger problem than  a mere repetition of the variables: If one of the entries in  `$@` happens to be the **absolute** path to some file, your code would break.

I would use [realpath](https://linux.die.net/man/1/realpath) inside the loop:

```
absfile=$(realpath "$file")
[ -r "$absfile" ] && [ -f "$absfile" ] && . "$absfile"
```

Of course this would **silently** skip "buggy" entries of `file`, for instance if the name denotes a directory instead of a plain file or those you have no read access. Unless this is the desired behaviour, I would omit the tests and just source the file. If things aren't right, you get at least an explicit error message.